# What is the difference between "is having" and "has" in this sentence?

Tags: grammaticality, differences

what is the difference and which one is correct?

a) The shoe shop is having a sale this week.

b) the shoe shop has a sale this week.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Before asking "which", and "what", and "why", you need to show some effort in research.

Comment: In that context, none.  The two can be--and often are--used interchangeably.

Comment: Is this Indian-English? Or is it American English  i.e. MacDonalds "I'm loving this"

Comment: @Cascabel (a) is perfectly normal in British English. The continuous tense is used because the sale Is continuing all week!

Comment: For pete's sake; This is standard in any English.